# what is the coefficient of following expression

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, discrete-mathematics, combinations, computational-mathematics

what is the co-efficient of $x^{50}$ in the expansion of

$$\frac{1}{(1-x^{1.7})(1-x^{1.8})(1-x^{2.6})(1-x^{3.0})(1-x^{4.0})(1-x^{6.7})(1-x^{7.5})(1-x^{8.2})}$$

can you please explain me the logic

Comment: That's the same as the number of ways of solving $17x_1+18x_2+26x_3+30x_4+40x_5+67x_6+75x_7+82x_8=500$ for non-negative integers.

Comment: Note, though, that this question is a little meaningless - it implies a power series, for this function but this function cannot be defined analytically around $x=0$. It can if you set $x=z^{10}$, however, and then look for the coefficient of $z^{500}$ in the resulting power series...

Comment: For completeness: [it's 3071](http://wolfr.am/UkZu0H).

Comment: how did u get 3071?is there a formula?

Comment: See the link in my previous comment. It's just your polynomial with the replacement $x\to x^10$, and then asking for the 500th power.

Answer (score 2):

Using the expansion
$$\frac{1}{1-x}=1+x+x^2+x^3+\cdots\ ,$$
your product becomes
$$(1+x^{1.7}+x^{2\times1.7}+x^{3\times1.7}+\cdots)
  (1+x^{1.8}+x^{2\times1.8}+x^{3\times1.8}+\cdots)\cdots\ .$$
In expanding this, each term in the answer comes from multiplying one term out of each bracket.  For example, one of the terms is
$$(x^{1.7})(x^{2\times1.8})(x^{2.6})(1)(x^{5\times3.0})(1)(1)(x^{7.5})(1)
  =x^{30.4}\ .$$
You need to find out how many ways there are of doing this to get $x^{50}$ as your final answer.  I can't see any easy way of doing this, though a couple of fairly obvious possibilities are
$$(1)(1)(1)(x^{2\times3.0})(x^{11\times4.0})(1)(1)(1)=x^{50}$$
and
$$(1)(x^{5\times1.8})(1)(1)(1)(1)(1)(x^{5\times8.2})=x^{50}\ .$$

Comment: yes but im not sure how to get the total number of possibilities..

Comment: As I said, can't see any easy way.  Trial and error probably.  Start with taking $8.2$ six times, which is the maximum possible, and so on.

Comment: yes ok. thank you.